# Counting occurrences from a dict and pandas

Tags: pandas, dictionary

I'm still quite new to pandas and python, and would like to count the total number of occurrences of the same combination of variables across multiple DataFrames within a single dict.

I have created a dict consisting of six df. The key to each df is a year (1985, 1990, etc.) and consists of an index and single row of integers. The index is made up of two variables (both strings) and is separated by a comma while the integer represents the correlation between the two variables:

```
DO-PSPCp PT-WFrTo -0.067934
         PT-WSWFr -0.067903
         PT-Wtotl -0.060489
         PT-WSWTo -0.060485
DO-SSPop DO-PSPCp -0.050703
PS-SWPop DO-SSPCp -0.048588
```

I would like to know the total number of times a specific index is correlated within the entire dict as well as the years (key) and individual correlation. Ideally, the output would look something like this (integers truncated for space considerations):

```
DO-PSPCp PT-WFrTo 5 1985,1990,1995,2000 -0.06,-0.068,-0.07,-0.06,-0.06
DO-PSPCp PT-WSWFr 2 1985,2000 -0.067,-0.07
```

The code used to generate the list uses a calls a correlation function (get_correlation) using a list composed of larger df containing the above variables and minimum number of observations required per pair of columns (number) and passes back the calculations listed above:

```
for i in list:

    HighCorr = (get_correlations(list[i],number))

    HighCorr[i] = HighCorr.to_frame()
```

Comment: could you post some code how to generate such a dict / pandas dataframe similar to the one you have?

Comment: Sure, hope this is helpful Arco Bast:

Answer (score 0):

You can first convert your dict into 1 huge dataframe:

```
df = pd.concat(dictionary)
```

This should return you a multi-indexed dataframe, with the dictionary key as the the highest level index.

Next, you can set the index back to the original format:

```
df = df.reset_index().set_index(['String1', 'String2'])
```

Since you need to get the information for a specific index, use:

```
df.loc['Specific_str1', 'Specific_str2']
```

You can get what you need by doing various queries:

```
number_of_times = df.loc['Specific_str1', 'Specific_str2'].shape[0]

# The dictionary key will be called 'level_0' when you re-index it
dates = df.loc['Specific_str1', 'Specific_str2']['level_0']

corr = df.loc['Specific_str1', 'Specific_str2']['Correlation']
```

I can't quite figure out what output format you need, so you got to take it from here yourself..

Comment: Thanks for the help. The challenge that I'm having is that I don't want to have to type each of the variables ('Specific_str1', etc.) manually as these are likely to change with different correlation criteria.

Comment: @Newbie14, I still can't quite understand what you need. If you have a correlation criteria, use df[df['Correlation' == Criteria]].index to return the index you need. If you want everything, just loop through the index, and for each index return the relevant output (based on the 3 queries above).